# Is there a way in the text_to_word_sequence method in Keras to also filter out stopwords using the 'filters' parameter?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I've reviewed the official documentation of the `text_to_word_sequence` method in Keras [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/#text_to_word_sequence)

The code listed in the documentation is:

```
keras.preprocessing.text.text_to_word_sequence(text, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n', lower=True, split=' ')
```

I was wondering if there is a way to add something in the `filters` parameter that would also remove stopwords (such as from the `nltk` list of stopwords) i.e.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords.words('English')
```

I am aware that we can also remove stopwords via regular expressions (using a `_sre.SRE_Pattern`)  as below:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('English')) + r')\b\s*')
phrase = pattern.sub('', phrase)
```

My minimum verifiable example is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
text_to_word_sequence("The cat is in the hat!!!")

Output: ['the', 'cat', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'hat']
```

I would like the output to be :

```
['cat', 'hat']
```

**My question is this:**

Is there a way using the `filters` parameter in the `text_to_word_sequence` method to automatically filter out stopwords along with the special characters that it filters out by default? Such as by using a pattern (`_sre.SRE_Pattern`) etc?